# Locale-independent FBSDKGraphRequest

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I am interested in fetching user's gender from Facebook. The device locale is set to Russian. Code:

```
let FBRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(
    graphPath: "me",
    parameters: [
        "fields": "id, gender",
        "locale": "en_US"
    ]
)

FBRequest.startWithCompletionHandler(
    {
        (connection, result, error) -> () in
        if error == nil {
            print(result["gender"])
        }
    }
)
```

It prints "мужской" instead of "male". How can I get response ignoring the device locale? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should file a bug, it´s working fine for me with this api call: me?fields=gender&locale=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem as you. I'm trying to change the locale putting a key and value as "locale":"pt_BR" or "locale":"en_US". Both fail.

The only way I found out to resolve is by changing the line below in the file "FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m" (I installed last version SDK trough cocoapods) in the method called: - (NSString *)urlStringForSingleRequest:(FBSDKGraphRequest *)request forBatch:(BOOL)forBatch

request.parameters[@"locale"] = [NSLocale currentLocale].localeIdentifier;

to for example:

request.parameters[@"locale"] = @"en_US";

The SDK gets the current NSLocale of the device and overrides the parameter you put on it.